# Do I need to test this?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing some unit tests for my `MVC` application but I have some trouble about common sense.

So, I have a function in my model to test called add_Member. I'm using `CodeIgniter` that turns empty inputs `($_POST)` to 0. In `mysql`, 0 values are not considered as `NULL` values so the constraint NOT NULL on my column (ME_Email in this example) can't be applied.

In my controller, I'm checking if my field `$_POST['email']` is not empty and if it's a valid email. I do that before calling my add_Member function from my model.

My question is, do I need to test an empty post value in my add_Member ?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to test all the methods in your app. If you are gonna make any refactoring later, this will help you or if you deside just to extend this functionality in other classes. Also, this test can help you in the debbing process. My kind advice is to try to test all methods and functionalities.

Comment: This is one example, but if i'm doing this for only 1 application. I will loose hours coding useless unit testing isn't it ?

Comment: I can't agree that you will loose it. Of cource everything depends on the project itself. Unit testing is one way to proof the correctness of your code. If you are thinking that testing this is a waste of time, then don't test it(I am not sure how this line looks like but I guarantee that there is no offense in words), it depends from you.